# Retag request: [id3-tag] -> [id3]

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

- [id3-tag](/questions/tagged/id3-tag) - 27 questions, no wiki
- [id3](/questions/tagged/id3) - 132 questions, wiki excerpt proposed

I suggest that [id3-tag](/questions/tagged/id3-tag) be merged into [id3](/questions/tagged/id3), as they appear to mean the same thing, with the latter being more widely-used.

**Edit**: I found a few different libraries, all of course named "ID3Tag" or similar, that could make a case for a distinct tag:

- [id3tag](http://raa.ruby-lang.org/project/id3tag/), a native Ruby library for ID3 tags
- [org.blinkenlights.jid3.ID3Tag](http://jid3.blinkenlights.org/javadoc/org/blinkenlights/jid3/ID3Tag.html), a Java class for reading tags
- the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521938/compiling-id3tag asks about cross-compiling a library which I couldn't distinctly identify
- [ID3TagLib.Net](http://freecode.com/projects/id3taglibnet), a C# library

However I think questions about these libraries might be better served by the [id3](/questions/tagged/id3) tag.